# cypher query function apoc.periodic.iterate is not batching completely

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to apply `apoc.periodic.iterate` to set property values on a large number of nodes for a particular label. However, it was noticed that when running the `apoc.periodic.iterate()`, the function does not complete. The jobs end at approximately the same time around *1200 seconds* and only applies to about *400,000 nodes* each time. This results in jobs ending prematurely. As such, jobs have to run multiple times before completing the whole setting property process.

I am wondering if anyone has experienced this issue and how it was overcomed. I am also wondering if anyone can explain what is the underlying functionality of `apoc.periodic.iterate` that can possibility result in such an issue.

Due to privacy, an example code is seen below:

Python job run code:

```
cypher = "CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(\"MATCH (x:label1) RETURN x\", \"WITH x SET x.property1 ='value'\", {batchSize: 10000, batchMode: 'BATCH'})"
with driver.session(database = db) as session:
    session.run(cypher)
```

Note there is no syntax error. This method for cypher runs is fine for all other jobs. The only difference is that `label1` represents a large number of nodes on the database. I have tried adjusting the batch size to many different sizes but to no avail.

I look forward to everyone advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: Hi @cybersam, i have updated the post, with only the part of the code that executes the cypher. Other parts of the code are not related to DB interaction. Thank you for reviewing!

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't finish, but have you tried using `batchMode = BATCH_SINGLE`? Operation query becomes `foreach(b in $_batch | set b.property1=myvalue`